# to pop up numeric keypad with decimal in iOS browser

Tags: javascript, html

The form's input field is an amount and on mobile browsers it's expected to pop up numeric keypad with decimal and comma(for thousands separator). I have tried type="text" with pattern="[0-9]*" but it's not displaying as expected. As my project environment doesn't support testing localhost on my mobile except the stage url, I can't try all the regex patterns I find in the web help, so providing already tested samples would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: So did you try `type="number"` yet?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=to+pop+up+numeric+keypad+with+decimal+in+iOS+browser

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
<input type="number" />
```

If you want decimals, you should add the `step` attribute:

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" />
```

Comment: <input type="number" />  shows all the symbols along with the numbers while I need numbers and decimal, comma only.

when I tried type="text"  pattern="\-?\d+(\.\d{0,})?", on desktop testing it displays on console that the pattern is not correct.

Comment: @yespz I updated my answer. As for the commas, those will show up depending upon your device's settings. Devices in Europe, for example, will show the comma instead of the decimal, and vice versa for devices in the United States.